# How to access another object from within a listener in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, object, listener

I have a listener on one of the elements of the menu class `GraphMenu()` in my program that that needs to call a method of an existing object created outside that class and I can't seem to find a way to implement this.

I'm defining the method of the `panel` I need to call in the `GraphPanel()` class:

```
    public class GraphPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel textLabel, graphicLabel;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JPanel graphPanel;

    public void appendTextArea(String s) {
    textArea.append(s + '\n');
}
```

The listener of the `GraphMenu()` I need to call that method in is:

```
    public class GraphMenu {

    ...

    // Add the action listeners that identify the code to execute when the options are selected.
    menuItemLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

            // you can set the directory with the setCurrentDirectory method.
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                // User has selected to open the file.

                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

                try {
                    // Open the selected file
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                    // Output the contents to the console.
                    String nextLine = reader.readLine();

                    while ( nextLine != null ) {
                        panel.appendTextArea(nextLine);
                        System.out.println(nextLine);
                        nextLine = reader.readLine();
                    }

                    reader.close();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    System.err.println("Error while reading the file");
                }
            };
        }
    });
    ...
```

Is there a way I can call the `appendTextArea()` on the `panel` object as in the example above?

I'm creating the two objects of class `GraphPanel()` and `GraphMenu()` in the main function:

```
    GraphPanel panel = new GraphPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    GraphMenu menu = new GraphMenu();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu.setupMenu());
```

Comment: Pass the panel to the GraphMenu constructor, so that the menu has a reference to the panel it needs to update.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but it looks like in that case panel is accessible only inside the constructor and I still can't call the method on panel in a listener outside the constructor.

Comment: Well, of course, the constructor can save it in a field, or pass it to the method which adds the listener to the menu item.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have solved my problem.